# APSO in Libreoffice calc broken and cannot reinstall

Tags: python, libreoffice-calc

Today 10th July 2022 I was told an APSO update was available. I decided to go ahead with it but now APSO seems to have removed itself from my LibreOffice. I tried reinstalling it from the Extensions manager but an error occurs...
[image]

I've tried with a few other APSO's (diff. versions but still it won't install, e.g I download apso-v2 51.3 Kb, but that error appears. So now I have no APSO. I even reinstalled the latest version of LO 7.4.3.2 (Can anyone help me fix this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Which OS? Did you try to manually install the newest version from https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python ?

Comment: Linux Mint 20.3 Kernel 5.15 and yes, that v1.2.8 APSO version is the one I tried to install and generated the error message.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this with the standard mint packages. Do you have the 'libreoffice-script-provider-python' package installed? I've tested with Mint 20.3, Kernel 5.13 and LO 6.4.7.2 (everything installed using the package manager except APSO). Maybe you could try to start with a fresh user profile?

Comment: OK. I went into /home/mpa/.config/libreoffice directory and deleted the "4" directory, then did sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*, followed by sudo apt-get clean and finally
sudo apt-get autoremove. Then I reinstalled the .deb LO package and rebooted. After that I tried to run the downloaded apso-v2.oxt. LO opened and thankfully APSO got installed. It seems like there was something - a "stuck" file somewhere in the "4" folder that was causing the problem.
Thanks for trying to help tohuwawohu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported in your comment, the first thing to do when trying to fix an extension is to reset the LibreOffice user profile directory, or at least remove the part where the extension is installed.

https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile#Manual_procedure_.28all_versions.29

Removing the whole profile will require you to redo all your settings, but personally, I find that it's often good to have a fresh start anyway.